# Jquery set files data after drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, file

I wrote code for drag and drop files to area.
After i drag and drop several files i need create area for edit each file.
In area is hidden file input and show file name for edit, it's code in drop event:

```
                    var filesArr = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
                    for (var i = 0; i < filesArr.length; i++) {
                        var fileName = filesArr[i]['name'];
                        var str ='<div class="projectActionTypeFileInfo">'+fileName+'<input type="text" class="actionTypeFileName" value="'+fileName+'"> <input type="file" class="actionTypeFileInput"></div>';
                        
                        $(this).parents('.projectActionTypeFilesContainer:first').append(str);
                        
                        var fileInput = $(this).parents('.projectActionTypeFilesContainer:first').find('.actionTypeFileInput:last');
                        
                        fileInput.files = filesArr[i];
                        console.log(fileInput);
                    }
```

**PROBLEM** is that i cant set '**files**' prop to my file input.
For get file input i use this code:

```
                        var fileInput = $(this).parents('.projectActionTypeFilesContainer:first').find('.actionTypeFileInput:last');
```

Maybe need use only js object, but how can i get my element?
So, how can i solve this? Thanks

Comment: You can't set files on a file input for security reasons

Comment: But how in this case i can get info for each uploaded file?